# Installing Ubuntu and accessing NTFS drive

Tags: ntfs

I have two drives (C: , D:)  and both are formatted with NTFS.
I have installed Windows 8.1 on the C drive and stored important files on D:.
I want to install Ubuntu along side of Windows 8.1 by making a partition on C drive.
After making a partition and installing Ubuntu, will I be able to access the D drive in Ubuntu or will have have an issue with the fact that it is in NTFS format?

Comment: Yes you can access NTFS drives.

Answer (score 0):

C: drive is a **partition** and you will have to install Ubuntu on a different partition.

and

Yes, Ubuntu is capable of accessing and modifying data in NTFS.

Answer (score 0):

Your C: and D: might be two partitions on a single physical drive or two partitions on different drives. In order to install Ubuntu, you need to have a free partition. You can accomplish this in at least two ways:

(i) either you move your content from D: to C:

(ii) or you create a new partition by resizing one of your existing partitions (in C: or in D:).

You can do (ii) from Windows. In Win 8 **right click** on My Computer and choose "Manage". A window pops up: choose Disk Management in the nav. bar. Right click on the partition you want to shrink and choose "Shrink Volume". It only allows you to shrink the partition to the extent you don't damage any of the files in it. You get some unallocated space; you may define a new partition in there, if you don't Ubuntu will take care of that. Just don't format it from Windows: Ubuntu **can read and write ntfs partitions**, but it will format its own partition in ext3 (which in my opinion is far more efficient). Formatting your new partition as ntfs would be just a waste of time. At any rate, Ubuntu will automatically install in the free space or partition.

Three suggestions. First, backup your important files on D: **before resizing D: or C:**.

Second, check that the new partition will be at least some 50 GBytes.

Third, I'd prefer to shrink a data partition (most likely, D:) instead of the boot one, unless the latter is exceedingly large. If you are going to go on using Windows, you need to have a good amount of free space in it.

And you'll have no trouble at all to access your Windows ntfs partitions from Ubuntu, both from a file manager or from the command line. It takes a single click.

Good luck!

A.